# Role access for Sitecore admin tools like Update Installation Wizard

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

**NOTE: Sitecore 6.6 Update 6 (rev. 20130529)**

Hey folks, I'm trying to allow for certain users in a role to be able to access the admin tool for the Update Installation Wizard so that they can deploy .update packages to an environment.

However, short of giving these users full "is administrator" privileges, I can't seem to figure out which roles will give this access.

I've tried the following roles:

- sitecore\Developer
- sitecore\Sitecore Local Administrators

These pull in a variety of developing and maintaining roles and give most of the tools (including standard package installation).  However, users with this access are still prompted for login when visiting the admin URL (/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly does your .update package contain? Sitecore Items, code or both?

Comment: @jammykam Our TDS deployment packages typically contain items only, though occasionally we are also installing modules or Sitecore updates that contain both files and content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [Sitecore.Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship) as an alternative means of deploying Sitecore update packages into an environment.

Essentially the tool exposes an endpoint that allows remote installation of update packages over HTTP. This approach has some advantages over the Update Installation Wizard as it allows Indexing to be disabled whilst the package is installed, leading to faster package deployment.

Comment: I will look into Sitecore.Ship as an alternative, as well as using TDS automated deployments.  This should prevent the need for using the wizard page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as the folder structure would suggest (/sitecore/admin) the users need to be full Administrators.

The CheckSecurity() method of the UpdateInstallationWizard base class specifically checks for this:

```
private bool CheckSecurity()
{
  User user = Context.User;
  if ((Account) user != (Account) null && user.IsAdministrator)
    return true;
  SiteContext site = Context.Site;
  string url = (site != null ? site.LoginPage : string.Empty) + "?returnUrl=" + this.Server.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}.aspx{1}", (object) this.PageUrl, string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request.QueryString.ToString()) ? (object) string.Empty : (object) ("?" + this.Request.QueryString.ToString())));
  if (url.Length > 0)
    this.Response.Redirect(url, true);
  return false;
}
```

You can check this yourself in [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler. It's defined in class `Sitecore.Update.UpdateInstallationBase` in the `Sitecore.Update dll`

Comment: Thanks for the details @jammykan.  I was hoping for a way around the security, but that's pretty obviously a catch-all check.  I may need to investigate another solution.

Comment: You could look at creating your own wizard but with different security check, looks like quite a bit of work. Also http://www.webdatasource.com/2011/08/exporting-and-importing-packages-from-sitecore-through-code-using-sitecore-api/ but I can't recall if the .update packages would install this way. But generally it is not the way we work, since a failed install will cause a lot of issues and they need to be able to fix that, so the users would usually be developers. We only ever deploy templates, layouts etc from TDS, never content.

Comment: I agree, website content is not deployed with TDS.  I meant content in the term of database items, as opposed to files.  The main content tree is not part of our deployments.

Comment: Great. I would look at Sitecore.Ship as Kevin suggested, looks the way forward :)